# Imprimir lista de nombres en C

Tags: c++, punteros

La verdad estoy algo perdido en esto de los punteros y necesito ayuda con un programa
Se supone que debo introducir `n` para la cantidad de nombres que tendrá la lista, introducir uno a uno los nombres y al final debería mostrarme en forma de lista los nombres que ingrese pero al final solo me muestra el ultimo nombre que ingrese, gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void leer_cadena(int &);
void escribir_cadena(int &,char *);
char *nombre;

int main(){
    int n,i;
    printf("Ingresa el numero de nombres: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    leer_cadena(n);
    escribir_cadena(n,nombre);
    getch();
}

void leer_cadena(int &n)
{
    int L,i;
    char cadena[30];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngresa el nombre: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cadena);
        L=strlen(cadena);
        nombre=(char *)malloc(L*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(nombre,cadena);
    }
}

void escribir_cadena(int &n,char *cad){
    int i; 
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        while(*cad)
        {
            putchar(*cad++);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor indenta correctamente el código para que sea más fácil leer dónde empieza y acaba cada bucle, etc. No sólo por quienes lean la pregunta, sino también para ti mismo. Es mucho más dificil encontrar errores en un programa que mal indentado. Por otro lado, aunque el lenguaje es C, veo que usas paso por referencia en algunas funciones (ej: `int &n`), además de forma innecesaria, pues estas funciones no necesitan modificar el valor del parámetro recibido. Finalmente, yendo a tu pregunta, no hay en tu programa ningún vector o array donde guardar los nombres. Solo tienes una variable nombre.

Comment: ¿Hablamos de C o de C++? El encabezado dice C pero el código usa referencias... algo propio de C++ y que no compila en C...

Answer (score 2):

En `leer_cadena` lees un nombre escrito por el usuario `n` número de veces. Pero cada vez se lo asignas a la misma variable global: `nombre`.

Al momento de escribirlos en pantalla, sólo ves el nombre del último porque ese fue el último valor con el que sobreescribiste esa variable.

Como esto es C, no C++ (aunque en la definición de `leer_cadena` pasas `n` por referencia: `int& n`, y eso es de C++, pero lo más seguro es que sea un error o confusión), supongo que tendrías que crear un array dinámicamente, dependiendo de cuántos nombres vas a leer, e ir guardando ahí los nombres.

Y por cierto, no haces nada de limpieza de memoria, si reservas algo con `malloc`, en algún momento debes llamar `free`. Si usaras C++ sería `new`/`delete`;